# Problemas al resultado de un query

Tags: laravel-5, postgresql-9.3

estoy ejecutando un query en un controlador de laravel, pero cuando mi consulta termina no me entrega el resultado que necesito. Necesito que me entregue solo un correlativo en el listado final, puede que mi correlativo venga 30 veces, pero solo necesito que me muestre solo un registro.

```
$nw=VistaProductos::where('proceso', '=', '=', date("Y"))
       ->orderBy('id')
        ->distinct('correlativo')
        ->get();
```

Cuando me entrega el resltado, igual me aparecen datos repetidos, creo que mi distinct no esta funcionando, me podrían ayudar a que esto me funcione. 
Estoy trabajando con laravel y postgres

El resultado que me entrega es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que necesito es que solo me muestre un solo Juan Plaza y no todos

Comment: Hola, por favor plasma un ejemplo del error o resultado que estás obteniendo y qué se supone que debes obtener, gráficamente si es posible y replicando el error ya que tu explicación puede ser muy relativa y se puede entender cualquier cosa para darte una solución en específico, gracias

Comment: Igual prueba cambiar get por first para solo obtener un registro

Comment: Como adenda a los dos comentarios anteriores: importa cuál de los 30 valores muestre? Los 30 son iguales?

Comment: Acabo de modificar los datos y adjunto la imagen del resultado

Comment: Puedes probar con `get()->unique('correlativo')->values()->all();` para ver si te filtra solo un resultado

Comment: Jonathan, igual me trae datos repetidos